# Terraform destroy failing because Google SQL user owns databases

Tags: terraform

I'm using Terraform to provision a Google Cloud SQL PostgreSQL database using a google_sql_database_instance resource. I also create a user with a google_sql_user resource.

After applying, I deploy my application which creates databases owned by that user.

The problem is, when I `terraform destroy`, Terraform tries to delete the user before it deletes the database. It gets an error (which is expected; you can't delete Postgres users while they own databases). But Terraform doesn't need to delete the user, because the next step is to delete the whole database instance.

Is there a way to tell Terraform that deleting the google_sql_database_instance will have the effect of deleting the google_sql_user, so that Terraform doesn't try to explicity delete the user first and fail?

Answer (score 4):

Use terraform's `state rm` to tell it to forget that the users and database exist so it won't actively try to delete them (and fail) at destroy time.

I use a `destroy.sh` script:

```
terraform state rm module.your_server_name.google_sql_user.users \ 
     module.your_server_name.google_sql_database.your_database_name
terraform destroy $@
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it'll work but try to use `depends_on` for the instance resource like

```
depends_on = ["google_sql_database_instance.ResourceNameHere"]
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help; that dependency already implicitly exists.